# Use Manipulate to visualize how roots of a system of equations changes with parameters - SOLVED

Tags: equation-solving, functions, manipulate

I am editing this question, I hope to be able to respect the rules. My goal is to find the roots of a system of 6 nonlinear equations (they are actually more, this is a simplified version). The roots represent equilibrium wages and prices. I've written the following code:

```
Manipulate[
 Chop[FindRoot[
   {Nl == nl1[wl1, wh1] + nl2[wl2, wh2], Nh == nh1[wl1, wh1] + nh2[wl2, wh2], 
    (wl1/wl2) == (pH1/pH2)^α, (wh1/wh2) == (pH1/pH2)^α, 
    nl1[wl1, wh1]*wl1 + nh1[wl1, wh1]*wh1 == (pH1*H)/α, 
    nl2[wl2, wh2]*wl2 + nh2[wl2, wh2]*wh2 == (pH2*H)/α},
   {{wh1, 1}, {wh2, 1}, {wl1, 1}, {wl2, 1}, {pH1, 1.2}, {pH2, 1.2}}
  ]], 
  {α, 0.25}, {λ, 3}, {η, 0.5}, {ϕh1, 0.2}, {ϕh2, 0.2}, {ah, 5}, {am, 2},
  {A1g, 1}, {A2g, 1}, {Nh, 1}, {Nl, 1}, {H, 0.1}
]
```

where I have defined the functions involved in the equations as follows

```
nl1[wl1_, wh1_] := (wl1/(A1g*λ*η*(1 - ϕh1)^λ))^(1/(λ*\η - 1))*(1 
  + (wh1/wl1)^(η/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η - 1)))^((1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1));

nl2[wl2_, wh2_] := (wl2/(A2g*λ*η*(1 - ϕh2)^λ))^(1/(λ*\η - 1))*(1 + 
  (wh2/wl2)^(η/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η - 1)))^((1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1));    

nh1[wl1_, wh1_] := nl1[wl1, wh1]*(wh1/wl1)^(1/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η - 1)); 
nh2[wl2_, wh2_] := nl2[wl2, wh2]*(wh2/wl2)^(1/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η - 1));
```

I have two problems.

**First**, I am able to find the roots only if write the explicit functional forms in `FindRoot`. However, if I write the general functions defined above, I get:

> The function value <<1>> is not a list of numbers with dimensions {6} at {wh1, wh2, wl1, wl2, pH1, pH2} {1.`,1.`,1.`,1.`,1.2`,1.2`}

I guess the problem can be solved using `?NumericQ`. I have made many attempts but no success so far.

The **second problem**, more important, is that I want to evaluate the four functions I have defined above when the arguments take the value of the roots and see how their values change with the parameters, using `Manipulate`. I guess I have to define the solutions provided by `FindRoot` and then `Manipulate` the above defined function by forcing their arguments to take the value of the roots. Again, many attempts but no success.

---

UPDATE: I have managed to solve the **second problem** using the following code

```
sol[α_, λ_, η_, ϕh1_, ϕh2_, ϕm1_, ϕm2_, ah_, am_, A1g_, A2g_, Nh_, Nm_, Nl_, H_] := 
 Chop[FindRoot[{Nl == nl1[wl1, wh1] + nl2[wl2, wh2], 
 Nm == nm1[wm1] + nm2[wm2], 
 Nh == nh1[wl1, wh1] + nh2[wl2, wh2], (wh1/wh2) == (pH1/pH2)^α, (wl1/
 wl2) == (pH1/pH2)^α, (wm1/wm2) == (pH1/pH2)^α, 
 nl1[wl1, wh1]*wl1 + nh1[wl1, wh1]*wh1 == (pH1*H)/α, 
 nl2[wl2, wh2]*wl2 + nh2[wl2, wh2]*wh2 == (pH2*H)/α}, {{wh1, 0.5}, 
 {wh2, 0.5}, {wm1, 0.5}, {wm2, 0.5}, {wl1, 0.5}, {wl2, 0.5}, {pH1, 0.5}, {pH2, 
 0.5}}]];

 Manipulate[{nl1[wl1, wh1], nm1[wm1], nh1[wl1, wh1], nl2[wl2, wh2], 
 nm2[wm2], nh2[wl2, wh2]} /. sol[α, λ, η, ϕh1, \ 
 [Phi]h2, ϕm1, \ϕm2, ah, am, A1g, A2g, Nh, Nm, Nl, H], {α, 
 0.25}, {λ, 1.3}, {η, 0.6}, {ϕh1, 0.3}, {ϕh2, 
 0.3}, {ϕm1, 0.3}, {ϕm2, 0.3}, {ah, 2.5}, {am, 2.1}, {A1g, 
 1}, {A2g, 1}, {Nh, 1}, {Nm, 1}, {Nl, 1}, {H, 1, 2}, Initialization :> 
 (nl1[wl1_?NumericQ, wh1_?NumericQ] := (wl1/(A1g*λ*η*(1 - \ 
 [Phi]m1 - \ϕh1)^\ 
 [Lambda]))^(1/(λ*η - 1))*(1 + (wh1/wl1)^(η/(η - 1))* 
 ((1 - ϕm1 - \ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η - 
 1)))^((1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1));
 nl2[wl2_?NumericQ, wh2_?NumberQ] := (wl2/(A2g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm2 
 - \ϕh2)^\ 
 [Lambda]))^(1/(λ*η - 1))*(1 + (wh2/wl2)^(η/(η - 1))* 
 ((1 - ϕm2 - \ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η - 1)))^((1 - \ 
 [Lambda])/(λ*η - 1));
  nm1[wm1_?NumericQ] := (wm1/(A1g*η*ϕm1*am))^(1/(η - 1));
  nm2[wm2_?NumericQ] := (wm2/(A2g*η*ϕm2*am))^(1/(η - 1));
  nh1[wl1_?NumericQ, wh1_?NumericQ] := nl1[wl1, wh1]*(wh1/wl1)^(1/(η - 
  1))*((1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η - 1));
  nh2[wl2_?NumericQ, wh2_?NumericQ] := nl2[wl2, wh2]*(wh2/wl2)^(1/(η 
  -1))*((1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η - 1));)]
```

Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Comment: This is far too broad and vague. Give us an example.

Comment: Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. If  you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) it will inspire great answers. As it is, your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it lacks enough details.

Comment: Fabio, thank you for adding all the details. I have voted to reopen and reverted my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution using tips from linked topics, adding `_?NumericQ` and moving definitions to `Initialization` to match e.g. `A1g` with controller:

```
 Manipulate[
   Chop[FindRoot[{Nl==nl1[wl1,wh1]+nl2[wl2,wh2],Nh==nh1[wl1,wh1]+nh2[wl2,wh2],(wl1/wl2)==(pH1/pH2)^α,(wh1/wh2)==(pH1/pH2)^α,nl1[wl1,wh1]*wl1+nh1[wl1,wh1]*wh1==(pH1*H)/α,nl2[wl2,wh2]*wl2+nh2[wl2,wh2]*wh2==(pH2*H)/α},{{wh1,1},{wh2,1},{wl1,1},{wl2,1},{pH1,1.2},{pH2,1.2}}]],
  {α,0.25},{λ,3},{η,0.5},{ϕh1,0.2},{ϕh2,0.2},
  {ah,5},{am,2},{A1g,1},{A2g,1},{Nh,1},{Nl,1},{H,0.1},
  Initialization:>(
    nl1[wl1_?NumericQ,wh1_?NumericQ]:=(wl1/(A1g*λ*η*(1-ϕh1)^λ))^(1/(λ*η-1))*(1+(wh1/wl1)^(η/(η-1))*((1-ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η-1)))^((1-λ)/(λ*η-1));

    nl2[wl2_?NumericQ,wh2_?NumberQ]:=(wl2/(A2g*λ*η*(1-ϕh2)^λ))^(1/(λ*η-1))*(1+(wh2/wl2)^(η/(η-1))*((1-ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η-1)))^((1-λ)/(λ*η-1));

    nh1[wl1_?NumericQ,wh1_?NumericQ]:=nl1[wl1,wh1]*(wh1/wl1)^(1/(η-1))*((1-ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η-1));
    nh2[wl2_?NumericQ,wh2_?NumericQ]:=nl2[wl2,wh2]*(wh2/wl2)^(1/(η-1))*((1-ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η-1));
  )
]
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! This definitely solves my first problem. Thanks! Still I have to find a way to manipulate the defined functions moved to initialization, by forcing their arguments to take the value of the roots. I would like to try to do it in the same Manipulate operation but I have no clue. I guess I have to use .\ but don't know how.

Comment: @FabioCerina `f[x] /. {x -> 1}`

Comment: I think I have solved my second problem. I would like to share the code but the space here is limited. Can I answer my question somewhere? Thanks